# MAC spoof not working?

Tags: mac-address, mac-spoofing

I have set up our home router to only allow certain MAC addresses to connect. One way to test if the filter is working is to spoof a MAC address not in the list and trying to connect to the router. So I have used `macshift` already to change my MAC address. However it doesn't seem to work.

```
Before MAC spoofing:
```

[image]

```
After MAC spoofing:
```

[image]

As the above images show, the physical address stays the same despite "spoofing" the unlisted MAC address. As a result, I can still login (because my original MAC is allowed).

This behavior is the same in both Windows and Linux (macchanger also doesn't work).

+++++++ UPDATE +++++++++++++
It's an Atheros card.

Comment: Are you running CMD as an administrator of the PC?
Try using Technitium MAC Address Changer v5 (or higher) running as admin? Whats manufacturer is the NIC?

Comment: Actually TMAC was the first program that I have tried. I always get "Failed...For wireless...set first octet to '02'". How am I suppose to spoof non-'02'-beginning MAC addresses? Administrator privileges also didn't help (for TMAC and macshift).

Comment: just use another device to connect..

Comment: @MayankSharma I believe the better answer is "just use another device to connect because the problem with your device is ..."

Comment: well if i had the answer i would have not left a comment. ;)
can't really help with your MAC spoofing problem but you can check your MAC binding by using another device

Comment: In Windows MAC spoofing is usually done in network driver settings (usually called locally administered address). Oh and install vendor specific drivers, the built-in driver often doesn't expose that feature.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows vista and above, the OS allows change to specific MAC addresses only, which are, the addresses starting with `2A`. However, as far as I know, there is no such limitation in Linux. I suggest you try to spoof your MAC again in windows, this time choose an address starting with `2A` and see if it works this time.

EDIT:
It doesn't have to be exactly `2A`. See comments below for more details.

Comment: It's seems that you are correct. Any references to this information?

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly "2A", the two LSB of the first octet are reserved for unicast/multicast and local/global indication (the reason it's the LSB instead of MSB is that's the transmission order for ethernet). This explains it clearly: http://lizardsystems.com/wiki/change_mac_address/faq/change_mac_address_in_windows_7. The 2A-xx-xx prefix is currently unassigned according to the latest OUI list from IEEE.